# Custom colors in C3.js timeseries chart

Tags: javascript, d3.js, c3.js

I am trying to set custom colors in a c3.js timeseries chart following [this example](http://c3js.org/samples/timeseries.html). The first element of each array is used to identify the dataset, so if I have an array:

```
var datatest1 = ['data1', 30, 200, 100, 400, 150, 250];
```

the color property can be accessed like this:

```
colors: {data1:'#0000'}
```

or:

```
colors: {'data1':'#0000'}
```

However, if I use the first element of the array to access them:

```
var data1id =  datatest1[0];
```

and then:

```
colors: {data1id:'#0000'}
```

It fails. Not sure what I may doing wrong as I get no feedback in the browser...

Here is a working example:

```
var axis = ['x', '2013-01-01', '2013-01-02', '2013-01-03', '2013-01-04', '2013-01-05', '2013-01-06'];
var datatest2 = ['data2', 130, 340, 200, 500, 250, 350];
var datatest1 = ['data1', 30, 200, 100, 400, 150, 250];

var data1id =  datatest1[0];
var data2id =  datatest2[0];

var chart = c3.generate({
    data: {
        x: 'x',
        columns: [
            axis,
            datatest1,
            datatest2
        ],
        colors: {
            //data1: '#0000',
            //data2: '#0000'
            datatest1: '#0000',
            datatest2: '#0000'
        }
    },
    axis: {
        x: {
            type: 'timeseries',
            tick: {
                format: '%Y-%m-%d'
            }
        }
    }
});
```

----- EDIT
I am doing this because the data (including the identifier) is generated dynamically. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can dynamically create the colors object like this.

```
var colors = {};
colors[datatest1[0]] = '#0000';
colors[datatest2[0]] = '#0000';
```

then set it in the graph like this

```
var chart = c3.generate({
    data: {
        x: 'x',
        columns: [
            axis,
            datatest1,
            datatest2
        ],
        colors: colors  //set colors object created above
    },
    axis: {
        x: {
            type: 'timeseries',
            tick: {
                format: '%Y-%m-%d'
            }
        }
    }
});
```

working code [here](http://jsfiddle.net/jeqwd9La/)